# How to extend a general invitation? (if anyone wants to...)

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to say, "If anyone wants to meet up, please let me know" as a general invitation to a group of my friends.

Is this correct? もし誰か会いたいなら、声をかけてください。

I'm unsure if my usage of 誰か is correct in this situation.

Although not necessary, I'd also appreciate it if the invitation sounded casual. Do I have any other options besides just ending the sentence in 声をかけてね？

Answer (score 1):

> 「もし誰か会いたいなら、声をかけてください。」

Without being too strict, I already see two "problems" here.

1) The 「誰か会いたい」 part is ambiguous.  It can be taken to mean either "wanting to meet someone" or "someone wanting to meet me".

2) The word choice of 「会う」 itself.  It would sound somewhat ***heavy*** in the context of an up-coming meet-up with internet people if you have never met them before in real life.  I would recommend a lighter-sounding word choice of 「オフ会{かい}」 or 「ミートアップ」.　Internet Japanese is like another language altogether.

Thus, you could say something like:

「ミートアップに参加{さんか}ご希望{きぼう}の方{かた}は（気軽{きがる}に）声{こえ}をかけてください。」

Or more casually,

「ミートアップ参加希望の方、声をかけてね！」

Comment: What do you mean by heavy? I guess to add more context, I'm gonna be going around Japan and wanted to know if any of my friends around the country wanted to meet up when I visit their area. So it's directed to friends of varying degrees of closeness, but all friends I've hung out with prior nonetheless.